# How can maven-cargo2-plugin recognize that my Spring Boot application already has an embedded Tomcat running?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, tomcat

I have an application that I built with Spring MVC (so it's a web front end), Spring Data and so on.  It runs on an embedded Tomcat and I can reach the index by:

```
java -jar MyApplication.jar
```

Going to "https://localhost:8443" in a browser or curl

(I have a couple of runtime configurations in Eclipse that make this faster and easier as well.)

Right now, everything is in maven, and everything builds (including with standard unit tests) by using:

```
mvn clean install javadoc:javadoc
```

(This gives me a jar file, a sources jar, etc.)

To do my front-end and integration testing, I need to have the application running.  Basically, I need a fork or multiple threads (I guess that's right terminology?) where the first one will run my application or something, then the second one will run the tests.

Right now I'm trying to fiddle with maven-cargo2-plugin, but it's horking because it is having issues with the fact that my application has an embedded tomcat already running.  Which makes sense--if cargo is starting a tomcat, it doesn't want to find one already running.

I'm pretty sure I'm not the only one doing this, but I'm at a loss.  I've tried going through spring-boot-test to load the application context, and that isn't enough for my front end tests (HTMLUnit/Selenium).

I've gotten failsafe set up and this all runs in:

```
mvn verify
```

But I'm confused on how to configure the container for Cargo.  Is this an "embedded" type?  An "installed" type?  "remote" (even though it's on the same machine)?

Like I said, this is the final lap.  We have an executable jar already.  I just need it to start up and then run until the verify step is over.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encourage you to use the spring-boot:run plugin which is already shipped with spring-boot

Usage: `mvn clean spring-boot:run`

Comment: OK.  I understand maven, and it seems that will clean the maven project, and start up the application, but it doesn't address how to do it for the mvn verify step so that I can run my maven tests.  Could you please elaborate?

Comment: For integration tests in spring-boot environment, we have a great annotation `@SpringBootTest` for that. Have a look on this [tutorial](https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-test/) on how to use it ;)

Comment: The thing I was having issues with was HTMLUnit tests.  Yes, @SpringBootTest eventually ended up being the answer, but there weren't a lot of tutorials on how to use MockMVc and HTMLUnit tests, so I was trying to bring in cargo to run the application in a fork so that HTMLUnit could do the front end tests.